# Get the value of a parameter and make it the type of another parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

The behavior I'm looking for can be implemented with overloading:

```
function fun(elType: "input", params: Input): number;
function fun(elType: "swtich", params: Switch): number;
function fun(){
  return 2
}
```

Where if I run:

```
fun("swtich", SOMETHING_OF_SHAPE_SWITCH) //compiles
fun("input", SOMETHING_OF_SHAPE_INPUT) // error
fun("input", SOMETHING_OF_SHAPE_INPUT) //compiles
```

I was wondering if it can be done by checking the parameter directly:

```
interface Input {
  a: 2
}

interface Switch {
  b: 2
}

type ElType = {
  input: Input,
  switch: Switch,
}

const fun = <T extends keyof ElType>(elType: keyof ElType, params: ElType[typeof elType]) => { }
```

That's as close as I got but it allows both:

```
fun("input", {
  b: 2
})


fun("input", {
  a: 2
})
```

It seems that I'm close, but I'm a) not quite sure what's happening in this last example and b) not sure how to achieve the desired bahaviour.

It seems what I want to do is:

```
const fun = <T extends keyof ElType>(elType: keyof ElType, params: ElType[elType]) => {}
```

But I get the error: `type 'elType' cannot be used as an index type.`

[Here's a tsplayg4round I'm using if you want to play around.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyycAXMgEwEC%20BBoksiKAygO7BgIAW%20RyAI3JVaBMAE8MKAKIAbACqSUAXj7FQ2MOXSaANPwDOHLt3LtOPfaIQB7EAdwwsIZKoA885BAAekEABMDZABrCHEbGGQ5RSkAPgAKCAUlclDwyOilXWQMOCg4AFsDckypAG0kmIgAXQBKV1i%20GjonEHiAIg0cduzCYiFKGlqW5wQwYDtkVopE5KlyTsxu7Nz8ou0lsFryECwCgWgAbgJWsYmXadmqhaNxnh6cvMLi5HMTbeRd-aOT0fHJy61PrIKAQMBYKAuEQjEAzdq3YD3XoDCjUYZiJRoADyADdoLIbHB-K41MRkFcUshFpoHqtnhtNB8vgcoMcyeTKpT4cYkY81i83jwmXsWcdrHYHFNnABmbS4-GE4mqeJ0grkOAgcT1ZSNYHEUHgyGUMUw6UdLpgB7AsiDNFAA)

I've seen several libraries implement this pattern so I was wondering what's the most idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: Really close, just use `T`: `<T extends keyof ElType>(elType: T, params: ElType[T]) => ...`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the generic `T` but haven't used it! TypeScript doesn't know what to do with it so it ignores it.

```
<T extends keyof ElType>(elType: T, params: ElType[T]) => ...
```

Using it here allows TypeScript to infer what `T` is from `elType`, and once it knows what `T` is, you can use `ElType[T]` to get the right params.